# how to conditionally add the httpInterceptor in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to know how to conditionally add the httpInterceptor in angular 2. In angularjs, it was possible.

```
  if (httpProvider && httpProvider.interceptors) {
                        httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyTestInterceptor');
                    }
```

I am creating an angular library and I want to give user the freedom to use my httpInterceptor or use their own.

myLibrary

```
export class MyModule {

   static forRoot(config: MyConfig ): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
          {provide: MY_CONFIG, useValue: config} ,  MyService ,
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
      ]
    }
  }    
}
```

User Application

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, HomeComponent ,ContactComponent,ProductComponent,ErrorComponent,ProductDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

    MyModule.forRoot({
      //some config data
    })

  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Well, just tell them to add the interceptor to the providers of the application if they want to, or to not add it if they don't want to.

Comment: I'm not sure you should write a library while you have this kind of questions... what did you try?

Comment: @JBNizet - I am not sure what you are trying to say. User never adds the interceptors defined in my library to his module providers. That is done in my library module.

Comment: @smnbbrv - If I never try, I will never learn. See the updated answer.

Comment: And that's precisely what you need to change, to let the user add it to the providers only if he wants to.

Comment: Something like this ?  

return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
  ...(config.provider ? [config.provider] : [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }])
] }

Comment: No. Just don't add the interceptor to the providers. Let the user of your library do it if he/she wants to.

Comment: @JBNizet - It worked! Thank you for helping and being nice! If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it.